# Calculating moment of inertia about the $z$-axis of solid with constant density

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following math problem:

> Find the moment of inertia about the $z$-axis of the solid in the first octant that is bounded by the coordinate planes and the graph of $x+y+z=1$ if the density is constant.

The according to the solution manual, the limits of integration are $z_1=0$, $z_2=z-x-y$, $y_1=0$, $y_2=1-x$ and $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{1-x-y}((x^2+y^2)\cdot k)dv
$$

I don't understand why the upper limit of $y$ is $1-x$. Can someone explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the following figure of the region:

[image]

Since you were asking about the $y$ limits so we focus only on it. What is the equation of the segment which is connecting $A$ and $B$? I am sure you would say $y=1-x$. I draw it on the right separately. If we make a vertical line on $x-$ axis then the coordinate of the points of intersection would be $(x,\color{red}0)$ for the lower point and $(x,\color{red}{1-x})$ for the top point. Pick these red ones as limits for $y$.

Comment: ouch...a hand-drawn figure. You deserve my upvote for your effort.

Comment: @TroyWoo: Thanks. Sometimes I need a dynamical blackboard here. :-)

Comment: From your drawing I understand how does x relate to y but from the equation x+y+z=1, y is expressed as y=1-x-z why are we assuming z=0?

Comment: @Oli: Because the triangle you see above is in `xy` plane. See it again.